# UTM values always not set

Tags: android, google-analytics, utm

I'm trying to send some data from one app to another(not installed on device). I've started to use CampaignTrackingReceiver, but I have a strange issue. 
When a user opens PlayStore, click install, then open app on devices with original Android OS(pixel, nexus) my UTM values(`utm_source`, `utm_medium`) have `not set` value. 
BUT when I'm doing the same on samsung or xiaomi everything works. I'm getting my values from `utm_source`.

Why is it working like this? 
I was thinking that link can be shortened, but I cannot check this

Comment: did u manage to solve it ?

Comment: @KaustubhBhagwat nope. I decided to store data on my first app into ContentProvider and read data in the second app